# Clicking label doesn't check my input field

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I'm using the following code. The checkbox doesn't want to be checked with the style I gave it.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
       <div class="checkbox">
          <input name="remember" type="checkbox" ><label>Wachtwoord onthouden</label>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>'
```

And css:

```
col-md-4.control-label, #email, #password {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 300px;
    resize: none;
    font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    outline: none;

}

.btn.btn-link, .checkbox {
    display: block;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    color: $white;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left:0; top: 2px;
    width: 17px; height: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}

/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    content: '✔';
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 4px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    color: $background_color_green;
    transition: all .2s;
}

/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

It's pretty weird since I use the exact same style for some other part on the website, but it does work on there. It should work on both this part as that part, right?

Comment: You'll have to assign the label to the input using `<label for="remember">`

Comment: Hae you tried to add input on your declaration?

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to assign the label to the correct input, so either use the `for` attribute, or place your label around the input, (but that would break your current CSS code).

The following HTML should produce the desired result.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
       <div class="checkbox">
          <input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" ><label for="remember">Wachtwoord onthouden</label>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You are so smart!